# Divide people into two teams and don't assign same team who hate each other

Tags: algorithm

There are n people and want to assian them to two teams.
But someone hate each other so don't want to assign same team.
I want to maximize smaller size team member numbers.

for example, there are 5 people and 
1-2, 2-3, 3-1, 4-5 are hate each other.
then {1,5}, {2,4} assign is possible.

and 5 people and 
1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 1-5 are hate each other.
then {2,3}, {4,5} assign is possible.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How far did you get so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: if in doubt start with brute force and go from there (find a way to enumerate all subsets and filter the partitions based on their internal hate)

Comment: Any particular language or just pseudo code?

Comment: sorry. my english is not fluent. so I didn't explain detail. I could not find clue about this problem. is this problem a kind of bipartition graph?

Comment: Seems like a variant of maximal bi-partite subgraph, which is NP-Complete.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to "use" the most people as possible, then this problem is basically the optimization variant of maximal bi-partite subgraph, which is [NP-Hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness).

The maximal bi-partite subgraph problem:

> Given a graph `G=(V,E)`, find two sets `U1,U2 <= V` - such that:
>
> 1. for each `v,u` in `U1`, `(v,u)` is not in `E` (and similarly for `U2`)
> 2. `U1 [intersection] U2 = {}`
> 3. For all other sets `U1,U2` that follow rules (1),(2), `|U1|+|U2| >= |U1'| + |U2'|`

In your case, the "people" are the vertices, and there is an edge between two people if one doesn't like the other.

It is easy to see that optimal solution to one problem is also the optimal solution to the other.

Since the problem is NP-Complete, there is no known efficient optimal solution to it, however some approximation algorithms do exist, and if your number of people is fairly small, you might be able to use a brute force (exponential time) solution.